# what is default for log4j.appender.NAME.Append

Tags: log4j

during my work I have found something like that:
`log4j.appender.dailyFile.append=true`

I believe there is an error with not capital A in append, but my question is- is true default falue for 
log4j.appender.NAME.Append? It would suggest this line is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FileAppender API: setAppend()](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html#setAppend%28boolean%29)

To summarize: The default value **is infact true.** So, yes. Technically that addition into the property file would be pointless. But it could also arguably be an explicit call out to make sure people know that it will append. (Granted, the name APPENDER probably gave it away as well.)